# Rake db:seed refuses to insert data into a particular database column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I’m having a very peculiar thing happen when I run a seed program to add users to my Rails app -- one of the columns absolutely refuses to be populated. It’s a user populate method, with some of the elements generated by the Faker gem.

The Faker items work just fine and insert into the database, except for the Faker::Avatar method. So I decided to try my own custom string with a randomly generated number for the avatar number. But nothing worked.

Here is the Users table from the schema:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "email",                  limit: 191,   default: "", null: false
t.string   "encrypted_password",     limit: 191,   default: "", null: false
t.string   "reset_password_token",   limit: 191
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer  "sign_in_count",          limit: 4,     default: 0,  null: false
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.string   "current_sign_in_ip",     limit: 191
t.string   "last_sign_in_ip",        limit: 191
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.string   "first_name",             limit: 45
t.string   "last_name",              limit: 45
t.string   "username",               limit: 30
t.string   "location",               limit: 191
t.text     "profile",                limit: 65535
t.string   "avatar",                 limit: 191
  end
```

And here is the seeding method for the User:

```
1.times do
   user = User.create!(
   first_name: Faker::Name.first_name,
   last_name: Faker::Name.last_name,
   username: Faker::Internet.user_name,
   email: Faker::Internet.safe_email,
   password: Faker::Internet.password(8, 16),
   location: Faker::Address.city + ', ' + Faker::Address.state,
   profile: Faker::Lorem.sentence(rand(15..60)),
   avatar: 'avatar' + Random.rand(1...180).to_s + '.jpg'
```

I am trying to figure out why I can't insert anything into the avatar column, either from Faker or my own string. It just seems strange!

Comment: Can you please attach your User model and part of server log?

Comment: Does it work if you change to `avatar:  'avatar.jpg'`?

Comment: I've tried that too, with `avatar-default.jpg.` Doesn't work either.

Comment: Here is my user model: ( http://pastebin.com/cCiApdzL). And here is the log from a seeding: (http://pastebin.com/fkFLGGp4)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for Ruby class `Random` [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Random.html), the `rand` method does not support the signature you use.  This should work if you change your code to:

```
avatar: 'avatar' + Random.rand(180).to_s + '.jpg'
```

Comment: Even with this syntax, the method won't insert anything into the avatar column. The Faker::Avatar method would not insert either. I did have the random syntax wrong, but I trying to figure out why nothing is inserted into this column and only this one.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by the uploader that is mounted to your avatar field.

The easiest solution is to comment out the mount_uploader line, seed the data and then uncomment the line.

Comment: This is very accurate. Thanks